# Asynchronous Exception Handling Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, try-catch, try-except

I am trying to asynchronously read data from Azure Portal Blob storage, where each file is stored in different directories. The directories are inferred and some directories don’t exist — in which case it’ll throw a ResourceNotFoundError. For example, I have a list of directories (A, B, C) that exist and it retrieves csv file and save it to "res" without any error as below:

```
test_dirs = [‘aaa/A.csv, ‘bbb/B.csv’, ‘ccc/C.csv’]
res = await asyncio.gather(*(read_blob(f) for f in test_dirs))
```

However, if I were to include “ddd/D.csv” in the test_dirs list whose directory does not exist, it throws ResourceNotFoundError and nothing is saved in res.

In order to ignore/pass the directory which does not exist and throw a ResourceNotFoundError, I thought I could simply use try and except without list comprehension as below, but it throws a new warning message and does not save anything to the variable res

```
for f in test_dirs:
    try:
        res = await asyncio.gather(*(read_blob(f)))
    except:
        pass
```

*RuntimeWarning: coroutine ‘read_blob' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback*

**How can I use “try and except” to skip directories that don't exist and throw ResourceNotFoundError but still be able to asynchronously read and save data from directories that exist?**

FYI, below is the read_blob function:

```
async def read_blob(self,
                  blob_name: str,
                  **kwargs):

        assert isinstance(blob_name, str), f'{blob_name} is not a string'

        blob = (await self.download_blob(blob_name))#.readall()
        
        with BytesIO() as byte_stream:
            await blob.readinto(byte_stream)
            byte_stream.seek(0)
            return pd.read_parquet(byte_stream, engine='pyarrow')
```

Comment: Please note that `except: pass` is an anti pattern. You should only catch the specific exception e.g. `IOError`

Answer (score 0):

You can just handle it in the coroutine function (in this case, read_blob). So it will only affect the function's operation, not the whole event loop.
There may be better practices for this, but I guess this can solve the issue.